# Pull images from google search in c#

Tags: c#, image

I'm building an application in c# that needs to search google for images, pull the first result and display it.
How can I do it?
Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 3):

There is a (deprecated) [Google Image Search API](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103000009/http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/imagesearch) which you might use from your C# code. [Here is an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20111222204159/http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.html#basic_query) on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This could be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/google_image_search_api.aspx

Comment: I did screen scrapping in the past, too. Google changes their page layout way too often; I had to adjust my application every month or so.